# Population with embeded queries RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, reactive-extensions-js

I cannot figure out how can I solve the following problem.

There is an object type:

```
Box { 
    Fruit[n]: {
      Kinds[n]: {  
        id: string;
        name: string;
      }
    }
}
```

I got the box of fuits from an API call as an Observable (Angular2) [Fruit[]] then I want to populate its "navigation property" with another API call what gives back an observable as well like:

```
  Box.foreach(fruits =>
       fruits.foreach(f => 
           f.kinds.foreach(k => 
                k.name = kindservice.getKindName(k.id) // <- observer
    )))
```

How can I do it with RxJs?

I tried many ways, there are many mapper but I could not figure out yet.
I used the Observable.from(..) as well but there was no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your most inner loop has 2 problems:

1. You assign an observer to a value.
2. Your observer stays cold.

Try changing it to:

```
 Box.foreach(fruits =>
       fruits.foreach(f => 
           f.kinds.foreach(k => 
                kindservice.getKindName(k.id).subscribe(name => k.name = name)
    )))
```